# Ubuntu 22.04: Can't turn off CapsLock sometimes; How to resart the "keyboard input service"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, capslock

Somehow, my capslock turns on, and stays that way, no matter what i try. Seems that only the letters are affected - e.g. the upper row acts normally, i.e. !@#$ needs shift to be typed.

I have tried the tips related to accessibility, did not help.

When i restart the system, it acts normally.

Sometimes I can't reboot until some long process finishes.

For instance, sometimes I need to restart the touchpad using

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse; sudo modprobe psmouse
```

Is there a away to restart the keyboard in a similar way?

Comment: There is no "2022:4" version of Ubuntu, guesswork; corrected to 22.04

Comment: Have you tried to change the keyboard ?

Answer (score 0):

When it happened again, I remembered what I pressed by accident right before.

It's <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> which alters this behavior.

I'm not sure where does this feature come from. If anyone knows, maybe please post a feature request to make CapsLock turn this off.